# Is there a way to display an image in the browser without having a preview of the image in the developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, image, browser

I am working on a "quiz" web application, where I want to show a picture to the user for a very short time and then ask the user what he has seen.

I am looking for a way that makes it difficult to the user to cheat by using developer tools to look at the image for a longer time.

My first attempt was to load the image bas64 encoded from the server and then setting the image src via JavaScript by using a data-uri.

However Chrome developer tools still shows the preview of the image in the network tab, even when it is loaded via data-uri.

My next attempt was to render the image programmatically on a canvas element, but even then the picture shows up in the network tab of Chrome.

Does anybody have an idea how I could prevent a preview of a rendered picture showing up in browser developer tools?

(Note: Preventing an easy to find image preview is good enough for me, I am aware that users with enough knowledge could also go into the developer tools and decode the base64 encoded image themselves when they find the corresponding string ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can somehow encode your image and than pragmatically draw it on a canvas. For example, using server-size script split the image into a few pieces and encode it using base64 (you may, also, encode these base64 string, but I don't think it would help). Than using JavaScript decode every image and draw it on a canvas. At least, it won't be that easy to just look an original image in the network tab, because user would see a bunch of small images instead of a big one.

However, I think you should use Flash or Java for this task.

P.S.
I have an even better idea. Instead of small images, you images with different transparent and color. So you would get an original image only when you draw all of them in the same position.

Comment: +1: I like the idea of using multiple small images to build up 1 large image, would make it harder to put together.. as long as you don't name them, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: This is a very interesting solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the image from the DOM so it cannot be inspected.  If you give it an id, after you have shown your image, you can then remove it:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image-id');
image.parentNode.removeChild( image );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not prevent Chrome to show a preview of the loaded image in the network tab. It is very easy for the user to just go into the network tab click on the corresponding "request" (even when the image is programmatically loaded via data-uri) and see a preview of the picture even when the image is already removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt your base64 string and decrypt it before using in image:

`function encrypt(str, secret) {
    return str.split('').map(function(char){return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) ^ secret)}).join('');
}
var encrypted = encrypt("test", 239847923); // ͽͬͺͽ
var decrypted = encrypt(encrypted, 239847923); // test`

Please, make sure that you use same secret value for encryption and decryption.
This is simple XOR encryption, so you can easily implement it on server side.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ys490rx6/3/

Comment: Thanks for that input. However this does not solve my problem, that a user can see a preview of the picture in developer tools. Because I have to decrypt the string *before* setting putting it into the image src or a data-uri.

Comment: In developer tools user will see encrypted string. You should decode it right before putting in image's src attr, so it will be decoded right before became visible to user,

Comment: Unfortunately (for my use-case) developer tools also show a "request" when setting the decrypted string to the src of the image, even though this is not a real network request that transfers the data. I modified your fiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/ef3d1v2q/4/ - Just run the fiddle and open the network tab in Chrome dev tools. You will see a preview of the image ...